# Maintaining the View of the Layout when user gets back to the View from another view

Tags: android, android-tabhost, activitygroup

I am working on an application where I am using the TabHost and I have four Tabs. Each of the tabs are given in a class MyTabHost that extends TabActivity.

Again I have one class that extends ActivityGroup and I have given all the tab classes in that class.

Now the problem is that when I move to another activity from one activity and when I come back to the previous activity, the position of the view gets refreshed and I don't want that. I want to maintain the view when I get back to the previously left activity on demand.

Is there any solution to anybody?

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if I understand you correctly and without source it is even harder.

Having said this, In Zwitscher I am also using tabs and switching between them does not change the content. Have a look at this code snippet:

https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TabWidget.java#L82

Perhaps this helps finding your issue.